# POST http://localhost:3000/sort net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I am trying to upload a file to the API, sort the numbers and then return the result in another text file that is available to download. I upload the file, and when I start the calculation I get the Internal Server Error. The API is running on port 3000 and I start the React App.js on port 3001.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

This is the API's app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/plain' }));

app.post('/sort', upload.single('inputFile'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    const input = req.file.buffer.toString().split('\n').map(Number);
    const result = input.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    const resultText = result.join('\n');
    fs.writeFile('result.txt', resultText, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send('File succesfully sorted!');
    });
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.send(resultText);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('API is listening on port 3000');
});
```

This is the React App.js:

```
 const [inputFile, setInputFile] = useState(null);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const [processingTime, setProcessingTime] = useState(null);

  const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    setInputFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const startCalculation = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const startTime = performance.now();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('inputFile', inputFile);
    console.log(inputFile)

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/sort", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      mode: 'no-cors',
    });

    const data = await response.text();
    console.log(data);
    setResult(data);
    setProcessingTime(performance.now() - startTime);

  };

  const handleDownload = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const file = new Blob([result], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = fileURL;
    link.download = 'result.txt';
    link.click();
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the client you are setting the input name to `inputFile`, however, on the backend you are telling `Multer` that the input name is `myFile`.

Change from this:

`upload.single("myFile")`

To this:

`upload.single("inputFile")`